# How to make gtk HPaned hide one side if pane clicked?

Tags: gtk

I ran several programs before where there is a paned widget with an arrow on its pane. Clicking the arrow hide the side to which the arrow was pointing. I found no way to achieve this in Gtk. any help please?

Comment: do you mean clicking the pane slider toggles the child widget to the left?!

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to do it is to put a `GtkExpander` in one side or both sides of the `GtkPaned`.